# How can I get my non-subscription-licensed Microsoft Office product key to stop claiming my subscription is expired?

Tags: microsoft-office, license

In 2017 I purchased, or tried to purchase, a non-subscription installation of Microsoft Office. Now, less than two years later, Microsoft Office tells me that my key is expired.

I have emailed the vendor yesterday, but also wanted to check in here. The paper trail from the vendor, PCDestination(.com), seems to be that I did in fact purchase a permanent installation:

> Dear Jonathan Hayward
>
> Thank you for placing an order on our website! :)
>
> The License Key(s) for your recent order: #131582  Will be found below.
>
> If you need help – visit our HELP-PAGE for instructions to install or activate your software!
>   Business Hours: Monday-Friday: 10am-5pm EST
>   Visit our website for Live Chat support! 
>   Thank You for your business! – PCDestination
>
> License Key
>   Product License Key
>   Microsoft Office Professional 2016 1-PC Lifetime Instant Download   *****-*****-*****-*****-*****

What can I do to get Microsoft Office to recognize that I purchased a permanent non-subscription key?

Comment: You're probably seeing this because there is a trial version installed besides the valid license. In any office product, check the license state, and it will tell you that it expired too. Here you can see what expired. You probably have a trial for Access installed that ran out. You can just uninstall those products to resolve the issue or google on how to unregister trial licenses

Comment: Use the Ospp.vbs to check the current Office license status on this computer: Run as Administrator to open Command Prompt, type 

    cscript.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office16\"ospp.vbs /dstatus

If you are running 32-bit Office 2016 on a 64-bit operating system, the script is: 

    cscript.exe "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office16\"ospp.vbs /dstatus 
Check if there is another subscription Office product listed. If there is, use the `ospp.vbs /unpkey xxxxx` (the last five character of the subscription product key) to remove it.